# Issues with null entries using LINQ Join

Tags: linq, null, left-join

I have been really struggling with this for the past couple of days and after exhaustive googling and haven't managed to work out quite how to do it. I am very new to LINQ and C#. Basically, I am trying to join two tables, all of one table, however the column I am trying to join to does contain nulls. Then joining onto that column a subset of another table.

What I would like to happen is that after joining I get all the information from the first table displayed, instead of what I am getting at the moment where only the columns which weren't null as displayed.

I am aware that this is a particually elegant explanation so I will post some simplified puesdo-code:

```
tblAsset                    tblLookUps

AssetTag int                Domain String
Type int                    DomainID int
Model int                   Description String
```

So information which would be in the tables would resemble:

```
100, 1, 1                   TYPE,  1, PC 
101, 1, null                TYPE,  2, Monitor 
102, 1, 2                   MODEL, 1, Old PC
103, 2, null                MODEL, 2, New PC
104, 2, null                MODEL, 3, Old Monitor
105, 2, 3                   MODEL, 4, New Monitor
```

So what I would like the LINQ query to give me is something like this

```
AssetTag Type TypeDescription Model ModelDescription
  100      1        PC          1        Old PC
  101      1        PC         null       null
  102      1        PC          2        New PC
  103      2      Monitor      null       null
  104      2      Monitor      null       null
  105      2      Monitor        3     Old Monitor
```

However at the moment the LINQ returns this:

```
AssetTag Type TypeDescription Model ModelDescription
  100      1        PC          1        Old PC
  102      1        PC          2        New PC
  105      2      Monitor       3      Old Monitor
```

So obviously when trying to join if the value is null it gets left out, which of course I understand, however I don't really care if it is null so would quite like to be able to see it!

My current LINQ looks like this:

```
  var AllAssets = from assets in dContext.tblAssets
                  join type in dContext.tblLookups.Where(x => x.Domain == "ASTYPE")
                       on assets.Type equals type.DomainID
                  join model in dContext.tblLookups.Where(x => x.Domain == "MODEL") 
                       on assets.Model equals model.DomainID
                  select new Asset
                  {
                   AssetTag = assets.AssetTag
                   TypeID = assets.Type
                   TypeDescription = type.Description
                   ModelID = assets.Model
                   ModelDescription = model.Description
                  }

  return AllAssets;
```

I have tried fiddling around with .DefaultIfEmpty() and several other things but I haven't managed to solve it and feel like I have reached the end of capabilities, any hints or pointers would be excellent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var q = from a in tblAssets
            join l in tblLookUps on a.Model equals l.DomainID
            into tblAssettblLookUps
            from l in tblAssettblLookUps.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                AssetTag  = a.AssetTag,
                Type = a.Type,                    
                Model = a.Model
                ModelDescription = l.Description
            };
```

Try query like this.

Comment: That was perfect! I have no idea how I missed that first time around, thank you so much!